# Topology on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I have been reading Royden and Fitzpatrick's Real Analysis (4th edition) lately, and I stumbled upon this exercise, which left me with a few questions:

**Let $X_1 = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of natural numbers and take $X = X_1 \cup \{ \omega \}$, where $\omega \notin X_1$. For each sequence $ s = \{ m_k \} $ of natural numbers and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define**

\begin{equation} B_{s, n} = \{\omega\}  \cup  \{(j, k)  : \ j \geq m_k \; \; \text{all} \; k \geq n \}\end{equation}

My first question is concerned with how to interpret the set to the right of the union. Is it suppose to be:

\begin{equation} (i_1, i_2) \in \{(j, k)  : \ j \geq m_k \; \; \text{all} \; k \geq n \} \iff i_2 \geq n \; \: \wedge \; \; i_1 \geq m_{i_2} \tag{1} \end{equation}

or

\begin{equation} (i_1, i_2) \in \{(j, k)  : \ j \geq m_k \; \; \text{all} \; k \geq n \} \iff \forall \; i_2 \geq n \;, \; i_1 \geq m_{i_2} \tag{2}  \end{equation}

I'm inclined to assume that the first one is correct, since I feel the second one is somewhat ambiguous, but what is mainly throwing me off is the *all* in the definition.

The authors go on with the exercise and comment that:

**The sets $B_{s, n}$ together with the singleton sets $\{(j, k)\}$ form a base for a topology on $X$.**

My second question is if this topology has a specific name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Arens-Fort space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens-Fort_space). The Wikipedia description makes it quite clear what the basic open sets are. The $m_k$ are just to ensure the “all except finitely many” elements in a column. The $n$ is to mark the end of the finitely many "exception columns", as it were.

So $(j,k) \in B_{s,n}$ iff ($j < n$) or ($j \ge n$ and $k \ge m_k)$.

Note that your text actually choses the symmetric representation: all rows except finitely many contain all but finitely elements. It's an equivalent description, in the sense that the results are homeomorphic by mirroring.

Comment: The role of $j$ and $k$ in your answer are reversed right? Also, if we considered $n = 10$, then would $(100, 7) \in B_{s, 10}$? Why is that?

Comment: @GiordanoRibeiro maybe your excerise text has reversed the roles of columns and rows?